# Connection pooling over several different database environment

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

If I have a setup where I need to run some SQL across several different database environments from a single Java program, is there a way to configure a connection pool to achieve this?

When I say several different database environments, what I mean is that I have several different versions of the same environment (staging, development, unit test, pre-prod etc). I want to create something that can run the same SQL query across each environment against the script logging table to ensure that each environment has had the same scripts run against them. We've had issues where the environments have got out of sync and bad things happened. While we are improving the process to try and reduce this, a tool is also required so we can check that what has been actually run.

Currently we have a pool property that passes in the URL that points to each environments connection.properties files. This is fine for the current connection pooling, but not sure if this will work for multiple databases.

Comment: Create a factory class which gives you different connections based on input parameter which would be your environment?

Comment: Set env variable/JNDI (if you run application server) or pass as parameter to Java program and differentiate the DB connection details. You can even put all details single or multiple property files. DEV.db.user=myUser etc or differant property file and load them according to your ENV variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to connect to many different databases at the same time then you should use a different connection pool for each database. It just doesn't make any sense to use the same pool for different databases as a connection to one database will never be able to be re-used for another database.

If you need to connect to a different database depending on external configuration (such as command-line, properties file) then you should arrange for the differing connection strings to be used depending on the environment setting.

Answer (score 0):

What is your application server? Best solution is to "hardcode" some symbolic connection pool name into the application. Then you can use the same signed version of .jar/.war/.ear file in every environment.

To name the real database you can either use JNDI mapping on application server level. Or you can also use tnsnames.ora/sqlnet.ora(default domain) mapping as this is usual way how to manage this in Oracle world.